# Incorrect syntax when using an CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find double records in a table.
My goal is to examine the result first, and if ok then delete the doubles.

So the idea is to use a CTE to find all doubles, and leaving out the original record

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ChassisID, FileName, OpdrachtID,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChassisID, FileName, OpdrachtID ORDER BY ChassisID)
   FROM dbo.tblChassisVMac
)
SELECT FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
```

and after examining if all is correct I wanted to replace the `SELECT` by a `DELETE`

But I keep getting this error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

I probably am missing something trivial but I just cant see it

SQL Server 2014 (SP2)

Comment: please use columnname before from or * keyword

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginninator". :)

Comment: @Larnu corrected, that was my first stupid mistake in this query allthough this one did not matter really

Comment: @GuidoG it's just a pet hate of mine. :)

Comment: it isn't actually an error to put the ; before WITH, and in fact it can prevent errors if a WITH sentence gets pasted into a working Script where another sentence is terminated without ; (which can be valid).  There are numerous code sample on line putting the ; there, including Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your delete would look like this:

```
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

A `DELETE` statement does not normally specify columns, because it targets entire records for deletion.  On the other hand, a `SELECT` query needs to specify columns.  So the following select would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Comment: Yes I know that but how to fix the `incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'`error ?

Comment: @GuidoG Check the second part of my answer.  You need to select _something_.  But, in a delete, you don't specify any columns.

Comment: yes I see it now. Very stupid mistake probably because I started out with the delete

Answer (score 2):

You need to define at least one `expression` or `column` with `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT col1, . . .
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
```

You can delete the records as :

```
DELETE C
FROM CTE C
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use * before from keyword or use column name in select Query

```
  ;WITH CTE AS(
       SELECT ChassisID, FileName, OpdrachtID,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChassisID, FileName, OpdrachtID ORDER BY ChassisID)
       FROM dbo.tblChassisVMac
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When CTE is used, it has to be the first statement in a batch. 
Try using derived tables instead, as follows

```
IF @Block <> 'All'
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Columns FROM TableName) AS T
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Columns FROM TableName) AS T1
```